# Tradução das descrições das medalhas de tag

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização, medalhas

Fizeram lambança na tradução das descrições das medalhas de tag:

> Você deve ter uma pontuação total de N em pelo menos M respostas wiki não pertencentes à comunidade para ganhar esta medalha.

**Sugestão:**

> Você deve ter uma pontuação total de N em pelo menos M respostas que não sejam Wiki da Comunidade para ganhar esta medalha.

Comment: Sem dúvidas, fiquei olhando para essa frase por meia hora antes de entendê-la plenamente.